# How does one get the ambient light conditions in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qml

I am planning to make an app which would switch between Light and Dark theme based on the ambient light conditions. So if it was a dark room, then the app would switch to a dark theme to reduce the strain on the eye and provide a pleasant experience.

I looked into Qt LightSensor API Docs [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qml-qtsensors-lightsensor-members.html) but on trying it on a sample device didnt work as expected. I also made sure to add **sensors** to the apparmor file. Has anyone got this working?

I would appreciate if the answer could include a working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed not yet hooked up to the backend yet (atm you can only get such sensor events using the platform-api directly). I included a story in the Phone Foundations backlog to hook this into Qt.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the appropriate API I guess, however, it doesn't seem to be hooked up to the backend yet. At least for me right now it it seems to give random values.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtsensors-ambientlightsensor.html

I think a bug report might be appropriate at this point.